# bringing latest date from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

teaching myself mysql the last few days and getting far?!

Im trying to get the latest compiled date from one table into another

what i have written so far

```
SELECT
case.case_number,
report.compiled_date
FROM
case
INNER JOIN report ON report.case_number = case.case_number
WHERE
case.case_active = 1
ORDER BY
case.case_number ASC,
report.compiled_date DESC
```

which gives me: -

```
case_number | compiled_Date
1001        | 23/07/2013
1001        | 23/06/2013
1001        | 01/03/2013
1001        | 02/02/2013
1002        | 24/12/2013
1002        | 23/09/2013
1002        | 01/08/2013
1003        | 23/09/2013
1003        | 12/09/2013
1004        | 23/11/2013
```

i have tried group by and max to no avail and think this is going to be a nested select if im reading right?

as i would expect to only see: -

```
case_number | compiled_Date
1001        | 23/07/2013
1002        | 24/12/2013
1003        | 23/09/2013
1004        | 23/11/2013
```

thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a GROUP BY clause to group by case_number, and then you can use aggregate function [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

```
SELECT
  case.case_number,
  MAX(report.compiled_date)
FROM
  case
  INNER JOIN report ON report.case_number = case.case_number
WHERE
  case.case_active = 1
GROUP BY
  case.case_number
ORDER BY
  case.case_number ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a GROUPBY clause

```
GROUP BY report.compiled_date
```